# Accessing elements of a page within iframe and setting variables in the parent page

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have a VF page (controller extension) which contains an iframe and a submit button within it. The iframe source points to another page. The source of this iframe is dynamically determined by a parameter from the parent page. Both the pages contain some inputtext values to be saved.

The question is how do I access the elements of iframe page and set their values within the parent page. The goal is to save values of all the elements. I am relatively new to VF and not able to dig deep into this.

This is what I tried - 
Set the value of apex:param to that of the iframe element using window.frames['iframename'].document.getElementByID(''Elementoninnerpage'). I'm not sure if this was the right way, but its not working (Its setting the whole text window.frames....as value)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved if both the domains of parent page and iframe page are same.
Else, we will get cross domain script error.

Comment: helpSFDC, please share your code, that way is easier to help you