# Closing Lightning Dialog

Tags: lightning

I created a button on my Account page, clicking it opens the dialog you see below:

[image]

My goal is to open a custom protocol in an iframe (which works perfectly), then close up the dialog automatically. I am having no luck trying to close the dialog automatically.

I've tried using javascript to go into the parent and close it, but I get a security error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://c.csXX.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://csXX.lightning.force.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must
>   match.

I tried adding both hosts to the CORS whitelist, but this had no effect.

Here is a somewhat similar question, but it also lacks an answer: [Accessing elements of a page within iframe and setting variables in the parent page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/accessing-elements-of-a-page-within-iframe-and-setting-variables-in-the-parent-p)

Also found this, but is a couple of years old. It suggests it is not at all possible: [iframe: Protocols, domains, and ports must match error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/iframe-protocols-domains-and-ports-must-match-error/17673#17673)

Here is a similar question, but also with no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO link hit as close as I think one can get: it reloads the whole page, which gets rid of the modal dialog. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it works pretty well in my situation.

I'm surprised by the Visualforce iframes being served from a different host, especially with the high reliance on iframes.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552514/visualforce-page-embedded-in-a-detail-page-that-needs-to-redirect-to-other-page

**Apex Controller Extension:**

```
public class Opp_Ext {
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public String redirectUrl {public get; private set;}
    public Boolean shouldRedirect {public get; private set;}

    public Opp_Ext(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.stdController = stdController;
        shouldRedirect = false;
    }

    public PageReference doStuffAndRedirect() {
        shouldRedirect = true;
        redirectUrl = stdController.view().getUrl();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Opp_Ext" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Do Stuff" action="{!doStuffAndRedirect}" rerender="redirectPanel" />
        <apex:outputPanel id="redirectPanel" >
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!shouldRedirect}">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.top.location.href = '{!redirectUrl}';
                </script>
            </apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [CORS](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html) functionality to address this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I added both of the urls to the CORS whitelist, but it did not change the behavior. I wonder if I did something wrong? But I added both individually,  just like: https://c.csXX.visual.force.com & https://csXX.lightning.force.com

Comment: Someone else had suggested that in an answer, then later removed it. I assumed that meant they didn't have faith in it, but I'm not sure.